# Prediction intervals for Lasso predictions

Tags: r, prediction, lasso

I am trying to find confidence (prediction) intervals for predictions of new data by a Lasso model. I've fitted a Lasso model to training data using the cv.glmnet function (i.e. by cross-validation) from the R glmnet package. Then I use the best lambda value from the cross-validation as fixed. I am aware that, using the fixedLassoInf function from the R selectiveInference package, I can generate confidence intervals and p-values for the estimated Lasso parameters. Can I use these to generate prediction intervals for predictions for new data, e.g. by using the predict.glmnet function?

Comment: Prediction intervals come from the likelihood, so if selectiveInference returns some estimate of the conditional variance which takes into account the penalization, then you could use that.